# C++ multidimensional array cannot increase above 0

Tags: c++, arrays

I have written C++ code that creates a multidimensional array, where each entry is 0 apart from 9 values that have 9 in them. I want to write code that loops through the array and if it finds an entry with a higher number than 0 in it, it takes one from that number and adds it to an adjacent cell. It seems to work, but only if the adjacent cell has a number higher than 0 in it already.

```
for(int x=0; x<max_row; x++){
for(int y=0; y<max_col; y++){
    if(map_array[x][y] > 0){

        int num = m_array[x][y];
        m_array[x][y]--; 
        m_array[x+1][y+1]++;

    }
}

}
```

This produces an array where you have a cluster of 8s and 9s surrounded by 0s, when there should be 1s on the outer edges.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `m_array[x+1][y+1]++;` is undefined behaviour if `max_*` is the size of the array and `x` is `max_row - 1` or `y` is `max_col - 1`.

Comment: No, I just want to loop through the entries in the array. (This is a response to something that seems to be deleted)

Comment: @image What is the adjacent cell?

Comment: I added an if statement to stop the program from attempting to add numbers outside the array, but the 9 cluster is in the middle so that didn't help here.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow adjacent means next too, here adjacent means an entry in the array that is next to the one that is being looped over.

Like, if I was looping through a normal array, array[2] would be adjacent to array[1].

Answer (score 1):

I have not understood what you are trying to do and what is the "adjacent cell" but in any case your loops are invalid. The valid loops could look at least as

```
for ( int x = 0; x < max_row; x++ )
{
   for ( int y = 1; y < max_col; y++ )
   {
      if ( map_array[x][y-1] > 0 )
      {
        m_array[x][y-1]--; 
        m_array[x][y]++;
      }
   }
}
```

Or maybe you want the following

```
int *p = reinterpret_cast<int *>( map_array );

for ( int i = 1; i < max_row * max_col; i++ )
{
    if ( p[i-1] > 0 )
    {
        --p[i-1];
        ++p[i];
    }
}

for ( const auto & a : map_array )
{
    for ( int x : a ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: What makes this loop more valid?

Comment: @image There is no an attempt to access memory beyond the array.